# Как переменной присвоить значение из strings.xml для локализации

Tags: android, c#, xml, xamarin, локализация

Сделал локализацию файла разметки axml. Все просто получилось, через Strings.xml.
Но есть переменные string, которые в коде тоже надо перевести. Например в коллекции:

```
nation = new Nation();
nation.Id= 1;
nation.Name = "Германия";
nations.Add(nation);
```

Попробовал сделать по аналогии, но конечно же ничего не получилось:

```
nation.Name = "@string/NationGermany";
```

Как мне присвоить переменной nation.Name нужное значение из Strings.xml, чтобы все работало как при .axml разметке в layout?

Comment: Что-то наподобие `context.Resources.GetString(Resources.String.NationGermany)`?

Comment: @VladD а какое значение присвоить context?

Comment: Вроде бы `Application.Context` или `Android.App.Application.Context`, если верить гуглу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ @VladD

```
 Context context = Application.Context;
 nation.Name = context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.NationGermany);
```

И все работает